# cat, grep & awk - both while read line & while read file in 1 loop?

Tags: awk, while-loop, grep, cat

---

Hi,

Thanks to alot of searching on stackoverflow (great resource!) last couple of days I succeeded in this, and even succeeded in the following issue, that was the output resulted in doubling of the lines everytime I ran the command. Thanks to an awk command which was able to remove double lines.
I'm pretty far in my search, but am missing 1 option.
Using both MacosX and linux by the way.

What I'm trying to do is parse through my notes *(all plain text .md files)*, searching for words/tags in a text file *(called greplist.txt)*, and parsing matched lines in separate text files with the same name as the searchword/tag *(eg @computer.md)*.

**Selection of contents of *greplist.txt* are:**

```
@home
@computer
@Next
@Waiting
```

**example contents of 2 .md files:**

*school.md:*

```
* find lost schoolbooks @home
* do homework @computer
```

*fun.md*

```
* play videogame @computer
```

**With this terminal command (that works great, but not perfect yet)**

```
$ cat greplist.txt | while read line; do grep -h "$line" *.md >> $line.md.tmp; mv $line.md.tmp $line.md; awk '!x[$0]++' < $line.md > $line.md.tmp && mv $line.md.tmp $line.md ;done
```

**Results**

The result for *@computer.md* :

```
* do homework @computer
* play videogame @computer
```

And *@home.md* would look like this

```
* find lost schoolbooks @home
```

So far so great! Already really really happy with this. Especially since the added moving/renaming of the files, it is also for me possible to add extra tasks/lines to the @ tag .md files, and be included in the file without being overwritten the next time I run the command. Awesomecakes!

Now the only thing I miss is that I wish that in the output of the @ tag .md files behind the task also the output also list the filename (without extensions) in between brackets behind the search result (so that nvalt can use this as an internal link)

**So the desired output of example *@computer.md* would become:**

```
* do homework @computer [[school]]
* play videogame @computer [[fun]]
```

I tried playing around with this with the -l and -H in the grep command instead of -h, but the output it just gets messy somehow. (Not even tried adding the bracket yet!)

Another this I tried was this, but it doesn't do anything it seams. It does however illustrate probably what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
$ cat greplist.txt | while read line; do grep -h "$line" *.md | while read filename; do echo "$filename" >> $line.md.tmp; mv $line.md.tmp $line.md; awk '!x[$0]++' < $line.md > $line.md.tmp && mv $line.md.tmp $line.md ;done
```

So the million Zimbabwean dollar question is: How to do this. I tried and tried, but this is above my skill level atm. Very eager to find out the solution!

Thanks in advance.

Daniel Dennis de Wit

Comment: What's confusing here is that you search to `@*.md` as well which should have been your generated files with the search right? Wouldn't that somehow be inconsistent or redundant? You even also write it back through the `mv` command. Just imagine if `@*.md` files already exist and you do `grep *.md` which would also include them..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outline solution seems like a fairly long-winded way to write the code.  This script uses `sed` to write an `awk` script and then runs `awk` so that it reads its program from standard input and applies it to all the '`.md`' files that don't start with an `@`.

```
sed 's!.*!/&/ { name=FILENAME; sub(/\\.md$/, "", name); printf "%s [[%s]]\\n", $0, name > "&.md" }!' greplist.txt |
awk -f - [!@]*.md
```

The version of `awk` on Mac OS X will read its program from standard input; so will GNU `awk`.  So, the technique it uses of writing the program on a pipe and reading the program from a pipe works with those versions.  If the worst comes to the worst, you'll have to save the output of `sed` into a temporary file, have `awk` read the program from the temporary file, and then remove the temporary file. It would be straight-forward to replace the `sed` with `awk`, so you'd have one `awk` process writing an `awk` program and a second `awk` process executing the program.

The generated `awk` code looks like:

```
/@home/ { name=FILENAME; sub(/\.md$/, "", name); printf "%s [[%s]]\n", $0, name > "@home.md" }
/@computer/ { name=FILENAME; sub(/\.md$/, "", name); printf "%s [[%s]]\n", $0, name > "@computer.md" }
/@Next/ { name=FILENAME; sub(/\.md$/, "", name); printf "%s [[%s]]\n", $0, name > "@Next.md" }
/@Waiting/ { name=FILENAME; sub(/\.md$/, "", name); printf "%s [[%s]]\n", $0, name > "@Waiting.md" }
```

The use of `!` in the `sed` script is simply the choice of a character that doesn't appear in the generated script.  Determining the basename of the file on each line is not 'efficient'; if your files are big enough, you can add a line such as:

```
{ if (FILENAME != oldname) { name = FILENAME; sub(/\.md$/, "", name); oldname = FILENAME } }
```

to the start of the `awk` script (how many ways can you think of to do that?).  You can then drop the per-line setting of `name`.

Do not attempt to run the program on the `@topic.md` files; it leads to confusion.

Comment: Works great I combined my old script to remove the old tags before running this script! One question though, how would I also add brackets around the contents of the greplist line [[@computer]] in here as well?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
grep -f greplist.txt *.md | awk ' match($0, /(.*).md:(.*)(@.*)/, vars) { print vars[2], "[[" vars[1] "]]" >> vars[3]".md.out"} '
```

What it does:

**grep** will output matched patterns in *greplist.txt* in the *.md* files:

```
fun.md:* play videogame @computer
school.md:* find lost schoolbooks @home
school.md:* do homework @computer
```

finally **awk** will move the file name to the back in the format you want and append each line to the corressponding *@*.md.out* file:

```
* play videogame @computer [[fun]]
* find lost schoolbooks @home [[school]]
* do homework @computer [[school]]
```

I added the *.out* on the file name so that the next time you execute the command it will not include the @* files.

**Note** that I'm not sure if the **awk** script will work on the Mac OS X awk.